# Ruby: Converting an array of dates into an array containing the occurrences per day

Tags: ruby

I'm still quite new to ruby but have been stuck on this problem for half a day.

I have an array of dates in integer form (e.g. `[1351136194, 1350142662, 1350118879]`) and I'm trying to turn it into an array containing the number of occurrences per day for the next 30 days.

Basically, I want to be able to query e.g. `array[0]` for the number of dates within today's range, `array[1]` for tomorrow etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.  Basically you convert the times to dates, then group them so you can easily identify duplicates.  Then create the array:

```
times = [1351136194, 1350142662, 1350118879]
dates = times.map{|t| Time.at(t).to_date}
occurences = dates.group_by{|d| d}
occurences_by_day = (Date.today..(Date.today + 30)).map{|d| occurences[d] ? occurences[d].size : 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1351136194, 1350142662, 1350118879]
hash = {}

arr.each do |int_date|
    date = Time.at(int_date).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
    hash.has_key?(date) ? hash[date] += 1 : hash[date] = 1
end

puts hash #{"25-Oct-2012"=>1, "13-Oct-2012"=>2}
```